# How do I install a regional language font in Sharepoint (WSS 3.0)?

Tags: wss-3.0, language

I want to implement Regional Language on WSS 3.0, something on the line of google transliteration, which will give an option to the users to choose the language, without affecting the working of other users.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to install the language pack that you wish to use and it will become available. The language pack needs to match your service pack level. There are instructions on how to do this [for WSS 3.0 here](http://www.leonmeijer.nl/archive/2008/04/15/97.aspx).